# Displaying data from MongoDB in handlebars

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, web, handlebars.js

I have two .hbs and one of them is a partial files, that particular partials contains variables to display data from the database.

This is index.hbs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> PayApp </title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Rubik&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/index.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/index.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <h1> PayApp </h1>

        <div id="content">
            <form id="payment_form">
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="field" placeholder="Name"> <br>
                <input type="number" name="refno" id="refno" class="field" placeholder="Reference Number"> <br>
                <input type="number" name="amount" id="amount" class="field" placeholder="Amount"> <br>
                <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="SUBMIT">
            </form>

            <p id="error"></p>

            <!--
                TODO: Display all transactions here. Each transaction should be retrieved from the database and displayed through rendering `../partials/card.hbs`.
            -->
            <div id="cards">
                {{this.name}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the partial card.hbs:

```
<div class="card">
    <img src="/images/icon.webp" class="icon">
    <div class="info">
        <p class="text"> {{name}} </p>
        <p class="text"> {{refno}} </p>
        <p class="text"> Php {{amount}} </p>
    </div>
    <button class="remove"> X </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Is your backend API responding with JSON data from mongoDB? If you tested it in Postman or API client?

Comment: @mcshakes yes it is! the data is being stored correctly.

Comment: Posted an answer below, but I'm also wondering what the "this" in your "this.name" is outputting

Answer (score 1):

So if I'm reading correctly, you are iterating through a collection of `cards` data and want to output each of that `card` in the form of that partial you have pasted below. It's been a while since I've played with templating, but I believe you would need something like:

```
{{#each cards}}
  {{> cardPartial name=name refno=refno amount=amount}}
{{/each}}
```

When your data is coming in like:

```
{
  cards: [
    {
      name: "cardName1",
      refno: "1",
      amount: "$300"
    },
    {
      name: "cardName2",
      refno: "2",
      amount: "$200"
    },
  ]
}
```

Try something like that, and see what happens if you simplify your partial output just to see the data? Let me know if it helps